# Is the following function concave? Can anyone hellp, please?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-analysis, maxima-minima

Is the function strictly concave $ν(x_1,x_2) = 2x_1 +x_2 − 9/2 ax_1^2 -2ax_2^2 − 6aρx_1x_2 $
over the set $D:= S =\{x_1+x_2=1\}$? Where $a>0$ and $|ρ|\leq1$. Applying the Hessian test, we get that the matrix is NSD(negative semi definite) when $ρ=1$ and ND otherwise. The set $S$ is convex but it is open. Can we apply the Hessian test also to closed sets??

Comment: What are NSD/ND?

Comment: The set $D$ is neither convex nor open.

Comment: Sorry but the set D is clearly convex. I do not claim that it is open either.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited** to respect the changes made to the original question.

First note that the domain of interest $D$ is convex.

Taking the Hessian is one way to begin.
We have
$$
H = \begin{pmatrix}
-9a & -6a\rho \\
-6a\rho & -4a
\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
Then the second derivative of $\nu$ along the set $D$ is
$$
(1,\,-1)\,
H \,
(1,\,-1)^{\mathrm{T}} = (12\rho -13)\,a < 0\,, \quad \text{since } |\rho|\leq1\,.
$$
Hence (by the second derivative condition) we see the function $\nu$ is strictly concave over $D$.

Comment: Sorry but the function was wrong. But are you sure that you can use the hessian test for ANY set ? Both open and closed?

Comment: @LearningProb Wikipedia assures us that "a twice continuously differentiable function of several variables is convex on a convex set if and only if its Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives is positive semidefinite on the interior of the convex set.".https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Functions_of_several_variables

Comment: "On interior of the convex set." But I think our convex set does not have interior points. So I do not understand how to prove the claimed result

Comment: @LearningProb we use the relative interior in this situation, which is just $D$ itself.

Comment: Sorry but how is the hessian PD if its determinant is $0$ when $p=0$? Why are we allowed to use the relative interior?

Comment: @LearningProb We have that $\mathrm{det}(H) = 36a(1-\rho)$ which is always positive. Your other question: we consider the restriction of $\nu$ to $D$, and the interior of $D$ with respect to itself is just $D$.

Comment: Thank you for your discussion but honestly It looks to me that the interior of D is the empty set.